# Cannot return whole JSON object back to calling function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to AJAX and I need to find a way to return an AJAX JSON response back to the calling function. Is there any way to achieve this.
My code snippet:

```
function requestAjaxWebService(webServiceName, method, jsonData) {
    var returnData;
    $.ajax({
        url: webServiceName,
        type: method,
        data : jsonData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            returnData = data;
        },
        error: function(error){
            returnData = "Server error";
        }
    });
    return returnData;
}
```

Comment: You could make the request synchronous which will wait for the request to complete before continuing execution, but this can cause problems elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.ajax()` [performs asynchronous HTTP request](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Hence, you can't return its response synchronously (which your code is trying to do).

If the request succeeds, the `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)` handler will get called at some point (you don't know when).

Here is one way you could modify your code:

```
function requestAjaxWebService(webServiceName, method, jsonData, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: webServiceName,
        type: method,
        data : jsonData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            callback(true, data); // some method that knows what to do with the data
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            callback(false, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

`callback` should be a reference to a method like:

```
function onData(isSuccess, dataOrError)
{
    if (isSuccess) {
        // do something with data
    } else {
        console.error(dataOrError);
    }
}
```

**Update** If the settings object is needed in the callback for some reason:

```
function onData(isSuccess, settings, jqXHR, errorThrown)
{
    if (isSuccess) {
        // do something with the data:
        // jqXHR.responseText or jqXHR.responseXML
    } else {
        // do something with error data:
        // errorThrown, jqXHR.status, jqXHR.statusText, jqXHR.statusCode()
    }
}

function requestAjaxWebService(webServiceName, method, jsonData, callback) {
    var settings = {
        url: webServiceName,
        type: method,
        data : jsonData,
        dataType: "json"
    };
    settings.success = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
        callback(true, settings, jqXHR);
    };
    settings.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        callback(false, settings, jqXHR, errorThrown);
    };
    $.ajax(settings);
}

requestAjaxWebService("name", "POST", "json", onData);
```

You can also use `.done()` and `.fail()` callbacks of jqxhr object instead of callbacks in `settings` object, as obiTheOne's answer suggests. It may look neater, but is not actually important here.

Comment: thanks for the response. But I need to get the whole object back to the calling function of requestAjaxWebService and not a separate callback. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by the 'whole object'? Is it the one you pass to `$.ajax()`? See update to the answer.

Comment: jqXHR object actually contains all off the response data... The only reason I can imagine for needing settings object returned to success callback is having sent json data handy.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.ajax is an asynchronous function, so normally it doesn't return anything.

You can anyway return a value to the original function by setting the async option to false, but is not recommended, because a synchronous request will block the rest execution of the rest of your code until a response will be returned.

```
function requestAjaxWebService(webServiceName, method, onSuccess, onFail) {
    var returnData;
        $.ajax({
            url: webServiceName,
            type: method,
            async: false,
            data : jsonData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                returnData = data;
            },
            error: function(error){
                returnData = "Server error";
            }
        });
    }
```

take a look at this example: [jsbin sync ajax example](http://jsbin.com/ruwaxu/edit?js,console)

You should instead use a callback (the standard way) to handle the response

```
function onSuccess (data) {
  console.log(data);
}

function onFail (error) {
  console.log('something went wrong');
}

function requestAjaxWebService(webServiceName, method, onSuccess, onFail) {
    $.ajax({
        url: webServiceName,
        type: method,
        data : jsonData,
        dataType: "json",
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError
    });
}
```

Or you can return a Promise (a sort of async object) that will change value as soon as the request will be fullfilled

```
function requestPromise (webServiceName, method) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: webServiceName,
        type: method,
        data : jsonData,
        dataType: "json"
    });
}

requestPromise('...', 'GET').done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

refs:
[jquery.ajax params](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: `$.ajax()` returns jqxhr object, that provides `.done()`, `.fail()` and `.always()` handlers. Otherwise you are right, this may be a cleaner way as compared to using callbacks.